# How do I develop a strategy for the board game Santorini?

Tags: santorini

I'm new to a chess-like board game called [Santorini](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/194655/santorini).

The basic rules are:

> The rules are simple. Each turn consists of 2 steps:
>
> 1. Move - move one of your builders into a neighboring space. You may move your Builder Pawn on the same level, step-up one level, or step down any number of levels.
> 2. Build - Then construct a building level adjacent to the builder you moved. When building on top of the third level, place a dome instead, removing that space from play.

> Winning the game - If either of your builders reaches the third level, you win.

How should I approach creating a strategy to consistently do well at this game?

Please note I'm not interested in adding in any 'God Powers' (modifiers) yet as I'd like to get a handle on the base game first.

[image]

Comment: BGG might be a helpful start. https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/194655/santorini/forums/67 there's a thread about running Santorini in something called Ai Ai, but it doesn't seem to go anywhere in terms of an outcome at the moment.

Comment: This appears the Ai Ai output for Man Vs Man. http://mrraow.com/uploads/AiAiReports/Santorini%20(Man%20vs%20Man).html#LevelsOfPlay Interpretation though is another thing

Comment: This might be a total beginner question, but is there any reason why "move one of your builders back and forth between two squares to win on turn 6" isn't the optimal strategy?

Answer (score 1):

Strategy is heavily dependent on builder placement in relation to your opponents builders. To win you need keep a few things in mind

- you need to be in a position to jump to the third level as often as possible
- it is important to be within range of your opponent to cap them if they are near an active  third level
- using your second worker to block square late game can prevent your opponent from being able to move or cap another square
- if you can ever wall in an opponents worker within one square by moving your worker in the way do so as this limits their play.

It is the combination of these that make your strategy. As it is an abstract game there is no hard and fast strategy that will guarantee a win.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think this is a fine answer for a question this broad.